# Why don't the freestyle lines show in the rendered image?

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I wanted to utilize freestyle for technical drawing, so I followed some simple tutorials. I activated the Freestyle checkbox in the Render menu, also activated the lineSet in the Render Layers menu. I hit F12, and I expected to see the edge lines in the rendered image, but alas, nothing. I used a simple white cube for testing purposes.

Can you help me? What did I miss?

All the best
Twerp

PS: Here is the file: [image] (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2422/)

Comment: Are you using cycles/internal?

Comment: If by internal you mean "blender render", its that.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Please show screenshots of your freestyle settings, render settings and render result; you could [upload the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for someone to look into it more closely. Note that freestyle won't appear while rendering image, only after render is done.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2422" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2422/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because (probably accidentally) you clicked on Exclusive, and now no edges are marked for inclusion. Click on inclusive, and you will see immediately some edges.

[image]

**EDIT** This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Damn straight it wasn't intentional ;) did that work for you? it didn't for me, just going through the workflow one more time to check it out.

Comment: Okay I tried the simplemost thing i could muster: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2424/ . Still not working, it SHOULD work, right? Is there more fundamental thing I could do wrong?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Now I re-dowloaded again your *original* file, and checked again, and it works. I just select inclusive, and thick green lines appear. Maybe you changed something and you are not working with your original settings. Please revert to that. I didn't check your second file.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the rendered result

Comment: This seems definitely to be working, yet it doesn't for me - what kind of system are you working on, if I might ask? I didn't change other settings, I don't know enough to do that ;)

Comment: Windows 8.1, Blender 2.78. Are you sure that if you download your original upload, and try changing this single setting, and wait until the render finishes (the freestyle limes appear only after the render finished), it doesn't work? It would be very strange.

Comment: Your second file (simpletest.blend) works for me without any changes. It renders black lines, not green.

Comment: I reopened the program, it worked now! Your suggestion that I accidentally seemed to have changed a standard setting turned out to be the right guess. Thank you for your patience!